# How to disable confirmation box on window (browser) close using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there some way how I can disable the confirmation box from appearing on closing the IE browser?

I an well acquainted with showing a custom message in this box using "onbeforeunload" and "onunload". However in my case I don't want to display this confirmation box all together and just close the browser window without any popup.

Comment: I think not using onbeforeunload, just onunload will do it.

Comment: @TonyDuffill What logic to write inside onunload?

Comment: If you just want to close the window, then window.close() - which makes me think you probably don't even need onunload - just allow the window to close itself...

Comment: Yes. It did. I added window.open(arguments) too. It worked! Thanks! @TonyDuffill

Comment: Crikey! - no idea what you're doing there, but if it works, then great.
All the best, 
Tony